# Role hierarchy in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, security, authorization, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

Is there a recommended/built-in way to implement Role hierarchies in ASP.NET Identity? I have four roles: Master, Admin, Manager, and Restricted. I want to develop a safe method for determining which Roles have access to certain functions. For example, I don't want Admins to be able to edit or create users with a Master role, but they should be able to edit both Manager and Restricted users.

One solution I thought of would be to make an enum as follows:

```
   public enum Roles
   {
       Master = 64,
       Admin = 16,
       Manager = 4,
       Restricted = 1
   }
```

And then use comparison operators to determine who is of a higher authorization level.

The problem with this is that it feels like I am beginning to write my own Auth system and would rather leave as much as possible to the security professionals who wrote Identity.

Is there an accepted and safe way to implement Role Hierarchies in ASP.NET Identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually trying to do is manage permissions. You could use Roles for that - if your permission groups are fairly straightforward, but real life is not normally like that. The recommended solution is to use a Claims-based approach, where you can assign individual actions as claims to a user's identity, and then query the current user to see if they have the requisite claim before they are permitted to perform an action.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: If the logic is as simple as “if role1 has more authority than role2”, would you still recommend laying out claims for each role?

Comment: I would, because I think querying a claims collection for one that says this user can edit a Master is a lot clearer than trying to establish some kind of hierarchy of roles, which you invariably have to go back to the source of an enum somewhere to check in 6 month's time when you've forgotten who can do what. And you've added 3 more roles, and one of them works slightly differently.... that's how real life works.

Comment: The link you provided specifically makes a note that claims should represent "what the subject is, not what the subject can do". How do you square this with the idea of using Claims as a method of managing permissions. I see this recommendation in a lot of places, but I struggle see how this isn't in direct opposition to the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: If you check the NestJS documentation on claims, they say the exact opposite: "A claim is a name-value pair that represents what the subject can do, not what the subject is." https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization#claims-based-authorization. I simply take the view that claims are data relating to a specific identity, which is similar to the W3C view of the world: https://www.w3.org/TR/vc-data-model-2.0/#claims